# How to capture Color from Camera in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kotlin, dart

I found this plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/color_picker_camera , but it's not working because it hasn't null safety.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following java code in flutter project via channels

```
int frameHeight1 = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;
    int frameWidth1 = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
    int rgb1[] = new int[frameWidth * frameHeight];
    decodeYUV420SP(rgb1, data, frameWidth, frameHeight);
    Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, frameWidth1, frameHeight1, Config.ARGB_8888);
    int pixel = bmp1.getPixel( x,y );
    int redValue1 = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue1 = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue1 = Color.green(pixel);
    int thiscolor1 = Color.rgb(redValue1, greenValue1, blueValue1);
```

Then use platform channels. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

[check this video also](https://youtu.be/k4f_VYIKAp8)

it will gives you this result

[image]